# why does this anacron job run hourly, not daily?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm running zulip on a virtual private server, and have created a script `backup-zulip` on my laptop (with ubuntu 20.04) to back up zulip via ssh. I want to run this script daily, so I put the line

```
@daily  10      backup-zulip    sudo -u username /home/username/bin/backup-zulip
```

into `/etc/anacrontab/`. However, now the backup seems to run *hourly* whenever the laptop is turned on, filling up my drive far too fast.

What's going on?

I wondered whether the script gets rerun each hour by anacron since it exits on error, but running it by hand returns `0`.

Is there a log file that I can look into? Searching for `cron` in `/var/log/` gives nothing.

My complete `/etc/anacrontab` looks as follows:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly

@daily  10      backup-zulip    sudo -u username /home/username/bin/backup-zulip
```

(If this is not the correct stack exchange for this question, where should I post it to?)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252107/963426) help?

Comment: Exactly same issue here! Shame there's no answers. Did you ever find out what was wrong?

Comment: @PeterSnow Yes, I figured it out. Replace `@daily` by `1` and it works. `@daily` doesn't exist. the only valid non-numerical interval is `@monthly`, since months do not have a fixed number of days.

Comment: @user313032 Oh what! That's incredible. Seems so many tutorials all got it wrong. Thanks for you help on this, I'm sure this will fix it. Gracias!

Comment: @PeterSnow yes, there are blogposts out there that suggest to use `@daily`. Maybe it was supported in an older version.

Comment: I feel kinda weird closing this question as duplicate, since it's you who figured it out. Please do not take the closure as hostile. The point of marking duplicates is to make them lead to good *answers*. If you chose to post an [actual answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) here (instead of a comment that answers the question) then I would close the other question.